# Google.Apis.MyBusinessAccountManagement.v1

Tags: google-api, google-api-dotnet-client, google-my-business-api

The Google.Apis.MyBusinessAccountManagement.v1 .NET client library calls itself v1. If I use that will I have access to the API v4.9 endpoints?

If not...how do I use the GoogleCredential from the client library with the v4.9 endpoints?

Ultimately, I'm trying to get all reviews from all accounts/groups/locations.

Here's where I am so far...

```
if(File.Exists(ApplicationVariables.CertPath)) { 
                    GoogleCredential credential;
                    using (var stream = new FileStream(ApplicationVariables.CertPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                    {
                        credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream).CreateScoped("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/business.manage");
                    }

                    var service = new MyBusinessAccountManagementService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                        {
                            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                            ApplicationName = "Google Reviews Downloader",
                        });

                    var accounts = await service.Accounts.List().ExecuteAsync();

                    Console.WriteLine("accounts:" + accounts);

                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably wont like this answer but here it is [My Business Account Management API](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/accountmanagement/rest) apears to have two versions  v1 and v4.9.

Yet when we check Nuget.org there is only one package available [Google.Apis.MyBusinessAccountManagement.v1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.MyBusinessAccountManagement.v1/)

This is because the packages are built using the [Google API Discovery Service api](https://developers.google.com/discovery/v1/reference/apis/list)

If we check that [discovery.list](https://discovery.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis) you will find that there is only one entry for My Business Account Management API and that is v1.  This means that v4.9 is not a discovery service api and there for will not be built as part of the [Google APIs .net client libary](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client)

Why is this probably because Google has started going building things under the [Google Cloud .net client library](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet) instead.  However i am not seeing any mention about the 4.9.

I know the lead developer on both libraries and have sent him an email to see if he knows where it might be located.  My bet is that its still being worked on and hasnt been released yet.

Comment: Response from my contact is that its in the works but the best link i have for you is this https://github.com/google/google-my-business-samples/tree/v4/csharp

Comment: Ok i have addional information. "the API team aren't planning on releasing a library for 4.9, but I believe the new API mentioned in https://developers.google.com/my-business/preview/content/upcoming_releases will be public"